# How to capture stack trace for Ncurses app?

Tags: stack-trace, ncurses

Typically, when running an application from the command line, I get a nicely printed trace when things go wrong. But, since I happen to be working on an Ncurses application, the trace gets mixed in with the interface that was running, and the output gets all jumbled. Like so:

[image: Jumbledygook stack trace]

Specifically, I'm working on this project: [todo-curses](https://github.com/lorentrogers/todo-curses).

I'm running the app as a Rake task, so I figured the `--trace` option would help me, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Is there a good way to log the output of the *app* to a file or something and *not* include the Ncurses interface with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application: curses writes to the standard output by default.  If you (as the developer of the curses application) use [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) for initializing the library rather than `initscr`, then you can tell it to write the screen interface to the standard error.

But developers of bindings for curses from other languages typically leave out `newterm` as an alternative, just to make things simple.  For instance, the Ruby curses shown on [github](https://github.com/ruby/curses/blob/master/ext/curses/curses.c) has this deficiency.  Perhaps a bug report is due.